# Compact set / Multifunction

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, compactness

Let $K(.)$ a multifunction defined on $\mathbb{R}$ defined as follows:
$$K(x):=\begin{cases} K=\{0\} \text{ if } x\neq0,\\
K=[-1,1] \text{ if } x=0.  \end{cases}$$

Can we deduce directly that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ $K(x)$ is a compact of $\mathbb{R}$ since $\{0\}$ and $[-1,1]$ are both compacts of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes. Why do you doubt that?

Comment: I was just checking, in a more general case if $K$ is defined on a partition of $\mathbb{R}^n$, we only have to check that in every partition $U_i$ the set $K(x)$ is compact, hence $K(x)$ is compact.

Answer (score 0):

$\{0\}$ and $[-1,1]$ are compact subsets of $ \mathbb R.$ Hence $K(x)$ is compact for each $x$.